# Anyone done an Objective-C Xode version of Osherove´s TDD Kata "String Calculator"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, tdd

Always trying to code better and I am interested in doing TDD for Objective-C and Xcode.
Do you know any post that implement something like [Roy Osherove´s "String Calculator"-Kata](http://osherove.com/tdd-kata-1/)

Update: [trying to find out how to speed up TDD on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743427/how-to-speed-up-tdd-flow-with-ios-and-objective-c-xcode)

Comment: I've started a repository on github as a place to start collecting objective-c based katas: https://github.com/twobitlabs/xcode-katas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did that. You can find the screencast and the Xcode project [here in my blog](http://dergraf.net/2010/09/tdd-kata/). I’ve written the text around it in german, but you should have no trouble playing the video or finding the download link.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use NSPredicate like this:

```
NSPredicate * parsed = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"6 * 7 = 0"];
NSExpression * left = [(NSComparisonPredicate *)parsed leftExpression];
NSNumber * result = [left expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];
NSLog(@"result: %@", result);
```

Look [here](http://funwithobjc.tumblr.com/post/1553469975/abusing-nspredicate) for more info on using NSPredicate in weird ways.