# How to speed up TDD flow with iOS and Objective-C/Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, tdd, ios

Have been searching for experiences on TDD with Objective-C and iOS development.
Previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628906/anyone-done-an-objective-c-xode-version-of-osheroves-tdd-kata-string-calculator) about "string calculator"-kata in Objective-C was useful (thanks).

But it would be nice to learn even more fluent iPhone-TDD.

Do you have some experience of how to use [UISpec](http://code.google.com/p/uispec/) (based on [Rspec](http://rspec.info/)), [iCuke](http://open.bekk.no/2010/06/02/automated-functional-testing-of-iphone-apps-with-icuke/) (based on [cucumber](http://cukes.info/)) or similar tools?

And if you also have got the flow going with autotesting (autoiphonetest.rb) like [Paul did in his his blog](http://blogofpaul.merecomplexities.com/articles/263), it would be very interesting feedback.

Here is a good post: [Test Driven Development in Objective-C with MacRuby](http://www.macruby.org/recipes/tdd-in-objective-c-with-macruby.html)

Comment: I'm starting new projects in this manner; found the follow screencast useful: http://vimeo.com/9394596

Comment: @petert: +1 if you would post the link as an answer

Comment: Glad it helps you out, thanks for vote!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the following screencast pretty useful http://vimeo.com/9394596 to get started.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps this helps: http://pragprog.com/magazines/2010-07/tdd-on-iphone-diy